# Some errors in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im new with MS SQL-Server. And i have a problem with this.
I have a query:

```
with by_segment as (
SELECT  
    Road.Road_ID,
    GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(Track.Track.STAsText(),4326) as the_geom,
    row_number() over (partition by road_id order by Segment_Id) as [rn],
    count(*) over (partition by road_id) as [c]
FROM dbo.Road
LEFT JOIN Segment_ID  ON Road.Road_ID = Segment_ID.Road_ID
LEFT JOIN Track ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Track.Segment_ID
),
roads_by_segment as (
select 
   road_id,
   the_geom,
   [rn],
   [c]
from by_segment
where [rn] = 1

union all

select 
   [a].road_id,
   [a].the_geom.STUnion([b].the_geom),
   [b].[rn],
   [b].[c]
from by_segment as [a]
inner join roads_by_segment as [b]
   on [a].segment_id = b.[segment_id]
   and [a].[rn] = [b].[rn]+1
)

select * from roads_by_segment where [rn] = [c]
```

But get errors (i try translate it from russian):

```
Message 209, level 16, state 1, line 5
Ambiguous column name "road_id".
Message 209, level 16, state 1, line 5
Ambiguous column name "Segment_Id".
Message209, level 16, state 1, line 6
Ambiguous column name "road_id".
```

Lines 5 and 6:

```
    row_number() over (partition by road_id order by Segment_Id) as [rn],
    count(*) over (partition by road_id) as [c]
```

Whats wrong in here?

**UPDATE**

I do all from `bluefeet` answer and get new error in line:

```
on [a].segment_id = b.[segment_id]
```

Its says:

```
Message 207, level 16, state 1, line 29
Ambiguous column name "segment_id".
Message 207, level 16, state 1, line 29
Ambiguous column name "segment_id".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to preface the `road_id` with the table that it is coming from. Whenever you have columns with the same name in multiple tables, you need to preface the column with the table name:

```
with by_segment as (
SELECT  
    Road.Road_ID,
    GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(Track.Track.STAsText(),4326) as the_geom,
    row_number() over (partition by Road.road_id order by Segment_ID.Segment_Id) as [rn],
    count(*) over (partition by Road.road_id) as [c]
FROM dbo.Road
LEFT JOIN Segment_ID  ON Road.Road_ID = Segment_ID.Road_ID
LEFT JOIN Track ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Track.Segment_ID
),
```

*Note: I used `Road.` but you might need to use `Segment_ID`*

Edit, for the second error you need to include the `segment_id` in the `roads_by_segment` and it doesn't appear that you are selecting the `Segment_id` in the `by_segment` CTE:

```
with by_segment as 
(
    SELECT  
        Segment_ID.Segment_ID, 
        Road.Road_ID,
        GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(Track.Track.STAsText(),4326) as the_geom,
        row_number() over (partition by Road.road_id order by Segment_ID.Segment_Id) as [rn],
        count(*) over (partition by Road.road_id) as [c]
    FROM dbo.Road
    LEFT JOIN Segment_ID  ON Road.Road_ID = Segment_ID.Road_ID
    LEFT JOIN Track ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Track.Segment_ID
),
roads_by_segment as 
(
    select 
       road_id,
       the_geom,
       [rn],
       [c],
       [segment_id]
    from by_segment
    where [rn] = 1
    union all
    select 
       [a].road_id,
       [a].the_geom.STUnion([b].the_geom),
       [b].[rn],
       [b].[c],
       [b].[segment_id]
    from by_segment as [a]
    inner join roads_by_segment as [b]
       on [a].segment_id = b.[segment_id]
       and [a].[rn] = [b].[rn]+1
)

select * from roads_by_segment where [rn] = [c]
```

Comment: +1 -- Don't forget about Segment_ID.Segment_ID as well

Comment: @sgeddes you are right, fixed

Comment: @bluefeet: Thanks now i dont get error in this lines. But get new error. Please look at question update.

Comment: @KliverMax in your second error, it doesn't look like you have selected `[segment_id]` in the `roads_by_segment`

Answer (score 1):

You need to qualify the column with the table name if the column exists in more than one table. In the row_number function specify Road.Road_ID or Segment_ID.Road_ID. Since you are doing a LEFT JOIN, you want to use Road.Road_ID. Same is true for Segment_ID.Segment_ID or Track.Segment_ID

Comment: Yeah thank i do it and its work. But now i have same error in another line can you help we with it?